# Ant zip: how to remove original directory from the path

Tags: ant, zip

I have this structure

```
component1/Database1/...
component1/Code/...

component2/Database2/...
component2/Code/...

etc...
```

I want to create a zip that has this structure:

```
Database1/...
Database2/...
etc...
```

With this code:

```
<zip destfile="DB.zip"
     basedir="BuildPath" includes="*/Database*/**">

</zip>
```

it creates:

```
component1/Database1/...
component2/Database2/...
```

Suggestions on how to get rid of the first directories?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a way to get this done by first copying the files into a temp folder and then creating the zip file.  I was not able so far to figure out how to combine the 2 steps into just one call to make it more efficient:

```
<copy todir="DBTemp" overwrite="false">
            <fileset dir="${SourceDirectory}">
                <include name="*/Database*/**" />
            </fileset>
            <cutdirsmapper dirs="1"/>
        </copy>

        <zip destfile="DB.zip" basedir="DBTemp"  />
```

The functionality that I was definitely not aware when I posted this question was the "cutdirsmapper ".  That allows me to create the structure in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try copying the folder structure to a temp folder and try zipping it?

`https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copydir.html`
`https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html`

Comment: I would have the same issue.  I would zip a structure that doesn't reflect what I am trying to create. I think if I can copy the files  in the correct location I can use the same code to zip them up.